# Android set all checkboxes to uncheked state on RecyclerView from another activity

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have an activity, `Start.java` and `CandidateAdapter.java` class who extends `RecyclerView.Adapter<CandidateAdapter.MyViewHolder>`.

On `CandidateAdapter.java`, I have a list of names with a checkbox for each name.

On `Start.java` when I push "save" button, I send with `LocalBroadcast` the value "false" to `CandidateAdapter.java` so that, after saving the state of each checkbox to a database I can uncheck all checkboxes.

I wrote on a `onBindViewHolder` method of `CandidateAdapter.java`, this code to achieve this:

```
if (!checkBoxStatus) holder.voteCheck.setChecked(false);
```

But its not working. The code  `holder.voteCheck.setChecked(false)` is not getting executed. Maybe because the `onBindViewHolder` method executed when loads for one time and with listeners I think...

Is it possible to set all checkboxes to uncheked state? I can send my code if is necessary.

```
enter code here
        public CandidateAdapter(Context c){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    mContext=c;
}
public CandidateAdapter(Context mContext,List<CandidateModel> candidateList){
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.candidateList=candidateList;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView name;
    public CheckBox voteCheck;
    public MyViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.nameCandidate);
        voteCheck =  view.findViewById(R.id.addVote);
        //This command to prevent the Recycler view from recycling it?s content
        this.setIsRecyclable(false);
    }
}

@Override
public CandidateAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


                    rowView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.row_list_item,parent,false);

    return new MyViewHolder(rowView);
     }
// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CandidateAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    //Create instance of Database Helper
    DatabaseHelper mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    //Set database to write mode
    db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //Create a ContentValue object with columns names to be the keys
    final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        final CandidateModel candidateModel = candidateList.get(position);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance((mContext)).registerReceiver(mMsgReciever,
                new IntentFilter("count_voters"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance((mContext)).registerReceiver(messageFromStartVoting,
                new IntentFilter("custom"));
        //Read clear message from StartVoting.java class
        BroadcastReceiver clearMessage = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                checkBoxStatus = intent.getBooleanExtra("set_check_boxes_to_false",false);
                Log.i("Receiver","Got message "+checkBoxStatus);
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance((mContext)).registerReceiver(clearMessage,
                new IntentFilter("customClearCheckboxes"));
        createCheckedHolder();
```

if (!checkBoxStatus)
 holder.voteCheck.setChecked(false);

```
        holder.name.setText(candidateModel.getCandidateName());
        holder.voteCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                checkedHolder[holder.getAdapterPosition()] = isChecked;
                int newposition=holder.getAdapterPosition()+1;
                if (checkedHolder[position] ) {
                    //Store votes for each voter to  2D boolean array
                  //  countVotes(votesOfCandidates, position, countFromStartVoting, isChecked, vtsOfCandidates, mContext);
                    switch (countFromStartVoting+1){
                        case 1:
                            values.put(DataContract.VoteEntry.COLUMN_VOTE_VOTER1,1);
                            //Update an existing row with data to database table and return a rowId
                            db.update(DataContract.VoteEntry.TABLE_NAME_VOTE, values, "_id="+newposition, null);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            values.put(DataContract.VoteEntry.COLUMN_VOTE_VOTER2,1);
                            //Update an existing row with data to database table and return a rowId
                            db.update(DataContract.VoteEntry.TABLE_NAME_VOTE, values, "_id="+newposition, null);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            values.put(DataContract.VoteEntry.COLUMN_VOTE_VOTER3,1);
                            //Update an existing row with data to database table and return a rowId
                            db.update(DataContract.VoteEntry.TABLE_NAME_VOTE, values, "_id="+newposition, null);
                            break;

                    }
                    //Count the clicked checkboxes +1
                    updateCheckedVotes(++counter);
                }
                else {
                  //  countVotes(votesOfCandidates, position, countFromStartVoting, isChecked, vtsOfCandidates, mContext);
                    switch (countFromStartVoting+1){
                        case 1:
                            values.put(DataContract.VoteEntry.COLUMN_VOTE_VOTER1,0);
                            //Update an existing row with data to database table and return a rowId
                            db.update(DataContract.VoteEntry.TABLE_NAME_VOTE, values, "_id="+newposition, null);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            values.put(DataContract.VoteEntry.COLUMN_VOTE_VOTER2,0);
                            //Update an existing row with data to database table and return a rowId
                            db.update(DataContract.VoteEntry.TABLE_NAME_VOTE, values, "_id="+newposition, null);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            values.put(DataContract.VoteEntry.COLUMN_VOTE_VOTER3,0);
                            //Update an existing row with data to database table and return a rowId
                            db.update(DataContract.VoteEntry.TABLE_NAME_VOTE, values, "_id="+newposition, null);
                            break;


                    }
                    //Count the clicked checkboxes -1
                    updateCheckedVotes(--counter);
               }
                Log.i(TAG, candidateModel.getCandidateName() + String.valueOf(position) + " " + isChecked +"??????? "+countFromStartVoting + " totalChecked boxes" + counter);
               // countFinalVotes(signal);
            }
        });
    } //end if statement
}
private void createCheckedHolder(){
    checkedHolder = new boolean[getItemCount()];
}
//Show the list of candidates
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return candidateList.size();
}
// I send with Broadcast to StartVoting.java class the checked and unchecked checkboxes
public void updateCheckedVotes(int mCounter){
    Intent intent = new Intent("update_text");
    intent.putExtra("checkedItems",mCounter);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public BroadcastReceiver mMsgReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        countFromStartVoting = intent.getIntExtra("count",1);
    }
};
public BroadcastReceiver messageFromStartVoting = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        signal = intent.getBooleanExtra("endOfVoting",false);
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Please share the code of your `CandidateAdapter.java` class.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh whole recyclerview or `notifyItemChanged(int position)` to refresh particular item to refresh view in recycler view.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)